# Error in Connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Tags: android, android-emulator, jtds

I'm trying to connect to **SQL-Server from android app** using `jtds.jdbc` Driver i downloaded jtds.1.3.0 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/)

When i added this jar file into my application and tried to connect from my app, it gave the following Error

```
Error in connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

Here is the Sample code which i'm trying to Connect

```
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();//Here it's breaking and Giving The Exception

String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip_address :1433/DBNAME;encrypt=fasle;user=xxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";

String username = "xxxxxx";

String password = "xxxxxxxxxx";

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);

Log.w("Connection","open");
```

Please Help me to solve the Issue.

Answer (score 2):

jtds 1.3.0 still has problem with android, use 1.2.7 or below instead, that would fix the ClassNotFoundException you are getting there (yes, that's the exception you are getting).

Answer (score 0):

The JTDS library does not use the `encrypt=true` configuration element. Instead use the `ssl=require` or `ssl=request` options

Example:

> jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[SERVER]/[DATABASE];ssl=require;